# How do I stop flashing 'More' option in category navigation?

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9

As I have navigation categories links in header, and I have one 'More' link as categories incrases,new categories move into a dropdown labeled "More".

Now whenever I refresh the page,the 'More'option flashes. I want to load that header only when the categories move into that 'More' option.

I'm open to other suggestions if anyone knows of a better method.

Comment: ~~ Through my crystal ball I see that your code doesn't work quite right. ~~

Comment: Right now you (presumably) have the page render with "more" visible by default, and then run a script to hide it if it's empty. 

Do the opposite of that.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank You..It works..!!!